# BugClipper integration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, bug-reporting

I have trouble integrating **BugClipper** into my project.

I followed the integration instructions mentioned on their [website](http://bugclipper.com/guides)
But, the when I continue with my build it throws the following error -

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x17eaf2f0 (not loaded) 
2014-07-24 12:34:15.457 BugClipper[371:60b] -[SMOCInvokerView smoc_width]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17eae380 
2014-07-24 12:34:15.459 BugClipper[371:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SMOCInvokerView smoc_width]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17eae380' 
*** First throw call stack: 
(0x2eafce83 0x391a66c7 0x2eb007b7 0x2eaff0af 0x2ea4ddc8 0x10e8bf 0x10e60f 0x3968b0af 0x3968bcdb 0x10e5e7 0x105861 0xea8e5 0x312f1aad 0x312f14f3 0x312ebb41 0x31286a07 0x31285cfd 0x312eb321 0x3373876d 0x33738357 0x2eac7777 0x2eac7713 0x2eac5edf 0x2ea30471 0x2ea30253 0x312ea5c3 0x312e5845 0xeaae5 0x3969fab7) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems the category is not loaded, better go to Build Settings of your Target App, and search for Other Linker Flag and add one line in there, `-ObjC -all_load`

This should definitely solve your problem.

Cheers